# Is there a way to watch a group of variables not in scope but in service using anagular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

For example given the following data from service

```
myService.var1
myService.var2
myService.var3
```

Normally you would need to do the following

```
    $scope.$watch(function(){
      return myService.var1
    }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    })

    $scope.$watch(function(){
      return myService.var2
    }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    })
```

But I want to watch the list of variable in one go.

I tried the following, but each have its own issue.

```
    // Max digest cycle iteration error
    $scope.$watch(function(){
      return {
                 var1: myService.var1,
                 var2: myService.var2  
             }
    }, function(newValue, oldValue) {

    })
```

And

```
    $scope.myVar1 = myService.var1
    $scope.myVar2 = myService.var2
    // this doesn't actually watch the service variable
    $scope.$watchGroup(['myVar1', 'myVar2'], function(newValue, oldValue) {

    })
```

Can someone point me a direction?

Comment: Why do you need to watch the variables in a service? Doing a watch is often bad practice, I'd question why you want to do this in the first place...

Comment: `Max digest` is because your watcher returns new object each time.

Answer (score 1):

Fix for max digest.
It happens because we create new instance of object each digest iteration.
Let's fix it:

```
var watched = {
  var1: myService.var1,
  var2: myService.var2  
};
$scope.$watch(function(){
  return watched;
  // return angular.toJson(watched); // serialized can be better
}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
});
```

---

Your `$watchGroup` will not work, because you are watch for copies of variables, not for original.

With followed fix we come to previous solution(almost):

```
$scope.vars = {var1: myService.var1, var2: myService.var2};
$scope.$watchGroup(['vars'], function(newValue, oldValue) {
});
```